# Showing Loading Animation on Image Button, when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image button:

```
<input type="image" src="https://en.opensuse.org/images/4/49/Amarok-logo-small.png">
```

and i want to show a loading animation on button(not whole page),when clicked.

i tried with a gif image, when clicked on button it showed but not exactly on button.

Comment: Please show some effort, what you have tried and what did not work.

Comment: You want this same animation to be placed exactly upon your image element? Do you use this animation on other places also, or you will need it on the image only?

Comment: No i want any loading animation , not exactly this. but i want it on image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show overlapping elements, a common approach is to use `absolute` (or `fixed`) positioning. To show the loader, placed above your img element, you can follow these steps:

1. Wrap your img element in a wrapper div and give this div `position: relative`. `absolute` position will also serve our purpose but that is more likely to affect your current layout.
2. Now, inside your wrapper div, add another div that will contain the loading animation (which may be a gif, or contain any other animation structure). Place this loader over your img element using `absolute` positioning and place it as per your requirements.

```js
// bind click event
// you can use any event to trigger this
document.querySelector("#show-loader").onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector(".loader-wrapper").className = "loader-wrapper loading";
};//
```

```css
.loader-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.loader-wrapper .loader{
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.loader-wrapper.loading .loader{
  display: block;
}
.loader-wrapper .loader span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  animation: zoom 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes zoom{
  0%{ transform: scale(1);}  
  50%{ transform: scale(2);}
  100%{ transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <input type="image" src="https://en.opensuse.org/images/4/49/Amarok-logo-small.png">
  
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div><!--#wrapper-->

<br />
<button id="show-loader">Show loader</button>
```

Comment: its awesome!! but what to do if i only want it when click on image and disappear after some seconds.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh can you use jQuery or only javascript?

Comment: yes i'm using JavaScript. as i said previously that i'm failed to load effect on onclick